# how to make a bar chart for specific column in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a bar chart for category column in python, i've imported a table  to python 2.

it is like blowing:

```
id  | category | name
 1      apple     xx
 2      banana    xx
 3      orange    xx
 4       apple    xx
```

now i want to produce a bar chart like this

[image]

Comment: it's not a service, what have you tried so far? have you googled it? try something, research, develop code, still you are in trouble, then ask.

Comment: i tried to use groupby('category').size(), but i don't know what to do next

Comment: i have done some research using .bar(left, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, hold=None, data=None, **kwargs)) method, but i can't split the category with number

Comment: You have to mention those in your question and make people believe you tried something or else you will receive downvotes...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using `pandas` here, you can call `plot(kind='bar')` on `value_counts`:

```
df['category'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Also

```
df['category'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

will work

If you want to keep the original data order then pass `sort=False`:

```
df['category'].value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: what if i use matplotlib.pyplot library?

Comment: `pandas` is compatible with `matplotlib`, the object returned by `bar` or `plot` are matplotlib` `axes` object

Comment: i wanna use bar(left, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, hold=None, data=None, **kwargs) this method, which allow me to

Comment: `bar` supports `kwargs` to `plot`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html#pandas.Series.plot